# Ubuntu LTS: Disable battery notification when plugged in

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, notification

I'm running on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. unfortunately, my battery is not new anymore and it struggles to keep the charge.
As a result, I keep getting notified that my battery is about to deplete, despite being connected to the power. (every time I switch app, the power consumption spikes and I get a notification )

While I would like to keep the notifications when unplugged, it's completely pointless to get them while my power is plugged-in.

I found a way to disable the notification, but is there a way to keep the battery notifications only when the power is not plugged in?

Comment: One way to do this would be to write a script that gets called every time the notebook is connected to (or disconnected from) power. It would update the thresholds for notifications via command line changes to the Gnome properties. Not sure how reliable this would be, though, as it's not something I've done with power ...